# Using slideshow like navigation with localscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, scrollto

How do you create the following?

On virtually every slideshow you have a previous and next arrow and a bunch of dot's indicating what "slide" you're viewing. I'd like to use this for an entire site. I'm using scrollTo-1.4.2 with localscroll-1.2.7, so it's a bunch of div's the user can scroll to.

I'd like to be able to have the dot's and back/next buttons to use like a menu. Does anyone know how to create this, or where I should start to create this?

Thanks!
(If you need me to post the html, js or css I'm using, tell me and I will)

Comment: I think I may be misunderstanding your intent.  If you post your code in a http://jsfiddle.net/, perhaps it might be a bit more clear.

Comment: Bit too much for jsfiddle. go to http://www.jorisvandijk.com/example/index.htm to see the sample site. the menu below has to become like a slideshow menu with prev/next links on either site of the menu items.

Comment: I think you underestimate jsfiddle . . . :)  Updated my answer.

Comment: Wow... that's pretty awsome! however... how do I create the back/next items? (And thanks for taking the time to help!)

Comment: Also... when I click a link within the page and not on the menu, the menu doesn't jump to the correct dot.

Comment: Updated the jsfiddle in my post.

Comment: Yeah! Now it updates the menu... but how about the prev next links?

Comment: Doh... forgot. You could implement that several ways.  You could keep a variable to know which one you are on and use that to generate links, or you could read and parse.  I'd probably go the first route.  I can't do anything on this for a day, but I'll check back in tomorrow if you haven't figured it out.

Comment: Thank you, I'll see if I can figure it out... I'm just getting started with jquery, but I understand what you're getting at.

Comment: I tried a whole lot of stuff... but I don't seem to be able to get it to work and to make matters worse... I crashed my computer erasing all files I created. I now have the jsfiddle you made... This is getting frustrating and it's such a simple feature, or it should be. Have you had any luck and time?

Comment: Sorry, I've been really busy and will be for a little while.  I'll post when I get the chance, mate.

Comment: Sure, no problem! I'm gonna have a go at it tomorrow, maybe I'll crack it.

Comment: The js libraries were taken down.  Do you no longer care about this project?

Comment: taken down? not sure what happened. I'll reupload all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Make a carousel.** As always, I recommend using the [jQuery cycle plug-in](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/). It has lots of options to really customize what it can do.

   - Be sure your markup degrades nicely for non-JavaScript.
   - Every slide in your slideshow should have a unique and human-understandable id.
   - An example of something I've done: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/
2. **Link the hash to the carousel.** When the page loads, you grab the hash and tell cycle that you want to start on that page.

If you need some help with the details, comment on this post.

---

**Update:** http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/QhvCU/embedded/result/

Comment: I don't want to create an image carousel... I want a 'pager' and back / next buttons to use with localscroll like it's a menu.

Comment: You can use cycle for plain html markup, not just images . . .